# IOS optimalization loading Images into UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiimageview, uiimage

Hello I’ve problem with loading images in my UITableViewCells. Ofcourse I use  dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier for my cells. The major problem appears when I scroll table really fast, and cells which displays images freeze app for a 0.1sec but It’s wierd and user unfriendly. Images are cashed in array as UIImage, only what I do with images is setting for UIImageView. Any solutions?

Comment: What is the size of your raw images and what is the size of your image view in the table cell?

Comment: 40x40 UIimageView in cell, but images are really big 2000x3000.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a scaled-down version of each image to use in your table view. When you display an image on screen for the first time iOS needs to decode that image, which of course will take longer if the image is bigger. This alone can cause a bad scrolling experience. But then for each image on screen the GPU has to read the huge image and scale it down. This also takes a lot of time and produces a lower quality rendering than scaling the image using Core Graphics.

Answer (score 0):

Images with 2000x3000 dimension is really big. Maybe try to crop it using MGImageUtilities(https://github.com/michaelhenry/MGImageUtilities)